# Access JSON Stringified data on Server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, list

I want to use the JSON Stringified Array on the server side ::

The FOrmat of Sent Stringified data is::

```
task:[{"TaskID":4,"OwnerID":1,"RecurrenceID":null,"Title":"Test Title1234","Description":"Desc... ","Start":"2014-04-28T01:00:00.000Z","End":"2014-04-30T06:00:00.000Z","RecurrenceRule":"","RecurrenceException":"Task Exception Occured","IsAllDay":false}]
```

And on Server Side I am trying to access is as::

```
public virtual JsonResult Test_UpdateSchedule(IList<SchedulerViewModel> task)
{
//Implementation Code
}
```

But I am not able to access it here.

My FOrmat of ViewModel is as below::

```
 public class SchedulerViewModel 
    {
        public int TaskID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start{get;set;}
        public DateTime End{get;set;}
        public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
        public int? RecurrenceID { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
        public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
        public int? OwnerID { get; set; }
        public string StartTimezone { get; set; }
        public string EndTimezone { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Put your ui also as its looking ok are you passing using jquery ajax request?? if so then store into cookie then access it at server side.....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your request is a `POST` and that your content type is `application/json`.

If you post how you're passing the data that might help us answer.