# Get JSON formatted data on Server Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am passing the JSON Stringified data using jquery AJAX as::

```
 $("#btnTest").click(function () {
        var models = [];
        models.push({ TaskID: 4, OwnerID: 1, RecurrenceID: null, Title: "Test Title213", Description: "Desc... "});
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:"/Home/Test_UpdateSchedule/",
                data: {models:JSON.stringify(models)},
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    //
                }
        });
    });
```

And on Server side I am trying to access it as::

```
public ActionResult Test_UpdateSchedule(List<SchedulerViewModel> models)
{
         //Code Implementation
}
```

But I am not getting the Data here on Server side. I am getting Count as 0.

My ViewModel is as::

```
public class SchedulerViewModel 
    {
        public int TaskID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
        public int? RecurrenceID { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
        public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
        public int? OwnerID { get; set; }
        public string StartTimezone { get; set; }
        public string EndTimezone { get; set; }

    }
```

How can I access the Data here on server side?

Comment: You need to convert it back into something that the server-side language understands. Here is the MS article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

Comment: @jeff Can you please tell me that what changes I have to do in my code?

Comment: Is this question different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354879/access-json-stringified-data-on-server-side

Answer (score 0):

Just change your JSON.stringify() like below.

```
    JSON.stringify({ models: models })
```

Now working ajax post will be.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Test_UpdateSchedule", "Home")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ models: models }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            //
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Org.json lib for converting json string to json object

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("your parameter string");

After covering into json object you can iterate and set in your class.

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense to me. Would you consider identifying the problem with the original code, where your code goes, and exactly how it fixes the problem? As it stands this answer isn't very helpful.